# FormsAuthentication get all currently active authenticated users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I use FormsAuthentication to authenticate users in my MVC4 app. Is it possible to get all currently logged users?

Comment: If it is enough for you then you can get the number of users currently accessing an application. with [Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getnumberofusersonline.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any method like that but you can try this

```
 List<MembershipUser> onlineUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>().Where(u => u.IsOnline == true).ToList();
```

> [Membership.GetAllUsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8swhya.aspx)
>
> Be careful when using the GetAllUsers method with very large user
>   databases, as the resulting MembershipUserCollection in your ASP.NET
>   page may degrade the performance of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I had to instantiate the collection before I could cast it:

```
private List<MembershipUser> GetAllUsers()
      {
          MembershipUserCollection MU_Coll = Membership.GetAllUsers();//.GetEnumerator()  ;//.Cast<MembershipUser>().Where(u => u.IsOnline == true).ToList();
          return MU_Coll.Cast<MembershipUser>().Where(u => u.IsOnline == true).ToList();
      }
```